# How to see when folder access permission is changed?

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions, chown

How to see when folder access permission is changed?

The folder now has 777 permission and I want to know when chmod command is run for it. Is it possible?

My OS is Ubuntu.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check .bash_history file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only read last modification time of i-node with

```
stat DIRECTORY
```

You can not see what was changed but for folders it should match most times.

If you like to monitor permission use a cron job to check permission of folder.
Something like

```
export MYFOLDER=/my/path/to/folder; if [ $(stat -c "%a" $MYFOLDER) != "777" ]; then chmod 777 $MYFOLDER; echo $MYFOLDER permission changed > /var/log/myfolder.log ;fi
```

UPDATE:
If you like to have a history of changes and who made what then install **auditd** and start service.

Configure a rule for your folder:

```
auditctl -w /tmp/test -p a -k tmp-watch-test
```

You can see what happens with

```
ausearch -k tmp-watch-test
```

or

```
ausearch -w -f /tmp/test
```

should produce something like this for changes

```
type=PATH msg=audit(1496747062.420:20649): item=0 name="/tmp/test" inode=453007 dev=fd:00 mode=040775 ouid=1000 ogid=1000 rdev=00:00 objtype=NORMAL
type=CWD msg=audit(1496747062.420:20649):  cwd="/home/myuser/workdir"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1496747062.420:20649): arch=c000003e syscall=268 success=yes exit=0 a0=ffffffffffffff9c a1=120c0f0 a2=1ed a3=7ffc37c58930 items=1 ppid=20482 pid=21369 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts0 ses=2895 comm="chmod" exe="/usr/bin/chmod" key="tmp-watch-test"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need "real-time" notification of the change, you can use `inotifywait` from the `inotify-tools` package. In the most basic form in a bash script:

```
inotifywait $thewatcheddirectory # will exit if something happens
echo "Something happened to $thewatcheddirectory"
```

In practice, the `inotifywait` output hints at what changed, and you can select what events should be checked.